# How do I print out a certain number of letters, based on what the user inputs?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Something like this

```
Underscores = int(input("Enter a number: "))
print("^" + Underscores + "^")
```

That's what I tried to do but it's not working, you might understand what I'm trying to do from that code. Basically, the user inputs how many "*" They want in a "^*^" emoji, such as if the input is 4, it prints out "^____^". If the input is 10, it prints out "^__________^" etc, thanks!

I've only tried this code so far, and looking through other sources online

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close. You can multiply strings in python so:

```
'_' * 4
```

gives you:

```
'____'
```

With that you only need a slight change to your code:

```
n = int(input("Enter a number: "))
print("^" + '_' * n  + "^")

# or maybe cleaner:
print("^{}^".format("_" * n))
```

Comment: Didn't know you can use {} like that, thanks!

Comment: @OpBanana that and more. Python has lots of [string functionality](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)